# Prevent pyspark/spark from transforming timestamp when creating a dataframe from a parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a parquet file into a dataframe. My goal is to verify that my time data (column type in parquet : timestamp) are ISO 8601.

The dates in time column look like this : 2021-03-13T05:34:27.100Z or 2021-03-13T05:34:27.100+0000

But when I read my dataframe, pyspark transform 2021-03-13T05:34:27.100Z into 2021-03-13 05:34:27.100

I want to keep the original format, but I can't figure out how to stop pyspark from doing this. I tried to use a custom schema with string for dates but I get this error: `Parquet column cannot be converted in file file.snappy.parquet. Column: [time], Expected: string, Found: INT96`

Also I tried using conf parameters but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Format is relevant, value is. Your Parquet holds  a timestamp not a string. When you say "The dates in time column look like this" it means in some system or with some tool. The Z at the end indicates UTC and this is also what you are seeing with Spark.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz In this case if the value is displayed I gues we can consider that it is in the right format (ISO8601) and if the value was not in the right format it will appear as null, right ? But now how can I differentiate a null value due to a bad format from a line without value?

Comment: For context, my parquet comes from the conversion of a json to parquet. And I would have liked to be able to detect conversion errors or bad formats after transforming the json to parquet.

Comment: How about converting back to json and then do the comparison?

Comment: Could do the trick to convert back to json or a csv. But it means I need to write en read which would not be efficient. Compared to preventing the transformation of pyspark or being able to read the column as a string